# Trigger Timestamps during a continous sample input Matlab

Tags: matlab, loops, triggers, timestamp, delay

I have a continous data sample stream from an amp feeding into matlab. Matlab creates random triggers and sends them via a serial port back to the amp which sends them back to matlab... a simple loop...

I now want to test the delay, so the time between sending the trigger and recieving it again...
I'm not asking for the exact lines of code, I just wanna know what kind of function would be best suited to create such timestamps within matlab. I need a relatively high precicion (ms range)...

Any tips?

Cheers,
toxic

Comment: you dont even need the actual timestamp (as in date + time) but just the time passed right? I feel like `tic` `toc` will do just perfectly

Comment: [this](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/tic.html) can help you

Comment: thanks guys, seems that is what I'm lookng for...